# Can I deduct an office space rental if I am not self employed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, business, oregon

As a remote worker, I'm looking at renting an office space $250/mo. I am not self employed but instead working for a company.

Is this expense tax deductible?

Comment: Do you work remotely for the company's convenience?

Comment: @HartCO I do work remotely for the company's convenience.